# doPost() method - save input in array of class

Tags: java, html, arrays, servlets, methods

I'm very new to java Servlets and the whole integration with HTML so this may be a recurring question, I'm sorry.

I'm supposed to add doPost() to the controller "AddToWaitingList.java" where it should save the name entered in "addClientToWaitingList.html" in the array of class "TheRestaurant"; It also should respond to the request with JSP "addClientToWaitingListResponse.jsp";

This is what I did:

```
<p>Add client to waiting list:
    <form method="post" action="waitingList">
        <input type="text" id="add-client-to-waiting-list" name="name" /> <input
            type="submit" id="add-client-to-waiting-list-button"
            value="Add client to waiting list" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            if (name == null)
                name = "World";
            request.setAttribute("TheRestaurant", name);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("addClientToWaitingListResponse.jsp").forward(request, response); 
        }
    </script>
```

It shows "HTTP ERROR 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL". What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Java is not JavaScript, so maybe consider to place write the servlet (his own class) ...

Comment: Have you got a method in your controller class with the ability to handle a POST request ?

Comment: I suggest you start with a good, basic tutorial about what is a servlet, what is a JSP, what is HTML. Try to understand which code runs in the server and which in the client. (You have a client-side script with server-side code there...) Let JavaScript out of the equation for start. Make sure you follow the tutorial step-by-step by running the code in an actual server.

Comment: I think I don't have enough knowledge right now, I'm going to take your advice and try to learn from the basics with some online courses. Thanks for the help